# Can't get Scala to recognize commons-logging-1.1.2.jar

Tags: scala, jar

I am running a program that requires the use of commons-logging-1.1.2.jar.  When I try to compile it using:

```
scalac -classpath ~/jars/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:~/jars/commons-logging-1.1.2.jar:. HDFS_Test.scala
```

I get an error that says:

```
warning: Class org.apache.commons.logging.Log not found - continuing with a stub.
```

I know the class is in the jar but it still doesn't find it.  Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash only expands tildes in arguments when they are at the start of a word. Confusingly, bash *does* expand tildes after colons *in variables*, so `CLASSPATH=~/jars/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:~/jars/commons-logging-1.1.2.jar scalac ...` should work, but if you want to use a command line argument you'll have to expand it by hand.

(My source here is http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html )

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why this worked but I replaced the ~ with the actual path and it cleared that error.  ~ worked with the 1st class, but for some reason the 2nd class needed the full path.

Comment: Which shell are you using?